# Zend_Navigation: How to add numberings in the menu items?

Tags: zend-framework, recursion, treeview, zend-navigation

I am generating XML from database records, then feeding it to Zend_Navigation to render it as treeview and before rendering I would like to add the level numbers, like a TOC numberings:

I have:

```
$partial = array('partials/menu.phtml', 'default');
$this->navigation()->menu()->setPartial($partial);
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('treeview')->render();
```

The output is dressed with ul/li(I need ul for treeview):

```
My First Web Page
     Nice Page
           Main Help
     Works
```

But I Need:

```
1.My First Web Page
     1.1 Nice Page
           1.1.1 Main Help
     1.2 Works
```

How can I dress each level with a number?

```
$navarray=$this->navigation()->menu()->toArray();
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($navarray[0]), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($it as $row) {       
/// ????
}
```

Thanks Arman.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could modify the partial to render an `ol` instead of `ul`, and then use some [CSS magic](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters) to render the numbering properly.

You can see the example #48 in the [Menu Helper documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.menu) to get some inspiration.

**EDIT:**

If you need to use the `ul` tag, then probably you'll need to add the "current depth" of the menu items by hand. There is a very similar question answered here: [PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator: Determining first and last item at each branch level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348100/php-recursiveiteratoriterator-determining-first-and-last-item-at-each-branch-lev).

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but OL does not work with jquery treeview plugin, it require ul lists.

Comment: @Arman: Yes, sorry I overlooked it in your question. I've just edited my answer above.